# How do I go about generating a sound at a specific frequency (guitar chord app) in c#

Tags: c#, guitar

I am working on a guitar toolbox application a component of which is a chord and scale dictionary.

My questions are:

1. If I know the frequency/pitch in khz of a given note, how can I generate an acceptable sound (maybe midi) at that pitch?
2. My second question is that chords are built up of 2 or more notes, how would I go about layering 2 or more notes in an appregio (played 1 after another and held to form the chord)?

If there are any pointers about that I have searched for and missed please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try taking a look at this and see if it helps: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dawate/archive/2009/06/24/intro-to-audio-programming-part-3-synthesizing-simple-wave-audio-using-c.aspx

Answer (score 1):

First, an arpeggio is a single note played in octaves, or a chord played one note at a time.  So, the concept of a two-note 'arpeggio' lives in the same place as an Unicorn.  There's no such thing.

You may be looking at the so-called 'power chords' that use two notes, generally on adjacent strings, and one fret apart.

To generate your tones, use the free app "Audacity" and it can give you all the standard tones just for the asking.  I once made a 2-hour long tone of just 440Hz for an experiment to determine variations of a guitar string over time to determine how tuning responds to temperature variations.

You can make tones easily in whatever length you prefer.